# AngularJS Binding doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm fairly new to Angular, and a simple binding doesn't work for me.

It just shows me `{{ trip.name }}` and `{{trip.created}}` just as they're written.

My controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app-trips")
        .controller("tripsController", tripsController);

    function tripsController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.trips = [{
            name: "US Trip",
            created: new Date()
        }, {
            name: "World Trip",
            created = new Date()
        }];
```

A part of my class:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app-trips.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/tripsController.js"></script>
}
<div class="row" ng-app="app-trips">

    <div ng-controller="tripsController as vm" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
            <tr ng-repeat="trip in vm.trips">
                <td>{{ trip.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ trip.created }}</td>
            </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
```

the view of the controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app-trips", ['ngSanitize']);
})();
```

BTW - supposedly according to the course I'm following, I don't need `['ngSanitize']` yet, but without it it doesn't even show the `DIV`s.

**EDIT**: as @jellyraptor noticed , I had a typo with = instead of :

**EDIT 2** :

It was the typo + the [`ngSanitize`] which I really didn't needed. I fixed the typo and passed an empty array and everything works. Thanks all

Comment: This is a guess.  Based on the fact that it doesn't work without `['ngSanitize']`, it seems like you never actually create your angular module.  The module is created when you supply a second (array) argument to `angular.module(moduleName, [array of dependencies])`.  Without that array, angular treats the expression as a getter only, and not a setter.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `controllerAs` syntax and here the variable is `vm`. so for access scope object use `vm` instead of `tripsController`

```
<tr ng-repeat="trip in vm.trips">
    <td>{{ trip.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ trip.created }}</td>
</tr>
```

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module("app-trips", []);
})();

  angular.module("app-trips")
    .controller("tripsController", tripsController);

  function tripsController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.trips = [{
      name: "US Trip",
      created: new Date()
    }, {
      name: "World Trip",
      created: new Date()
    }];
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app-trips" ng-controller="tripsController as vm" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="trip in vm.trips">
      <td>{{ trip.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ trip.created }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, I changed it to tripsController when I tried to fix this issue. That doesn't help me.

Comment: None .. if there were one I would have searched for the answer online..

Answer (score 1):

Either Angular isn't loading or it is encountering an error. Bring up the dev tools with F12 and see if there are errors in the console. Also in the console, you can type 'angular' and hit enter and if it reports that angular is undefined then angular is not loading properly.

Comment: The console is empty , and where can I type inside the consol ? :S

Comment: I hit 'angular' in the `Debugger` section and it found this line :` <script src="/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Depends on the browser. Generally the bottom line of the console output is where you can type. Look for `>` or `>>` on the console window.

Comment: Do you have an `ngApp` directive somewhere on the page? Maybe on the `<HTML>` or `<BODY>` tag? If not, then Angular is never really bootstrapping. (Unless you're bootstrapping it in code)

Comment: Oh, it return something.. `[Object object]     {callbacks: object{ ...} , version...`

Comment: Mmm yea I do.. look at the edit of the question, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: You didn't inject `ngSanitize` dependency.

Comment: `@section scripts` So you're using ASP.NET MVC? .

Comment: @Hadi It what it + a typo I made(see jellyraptor answer). I just deleted ngSanitize and passed an empty array and it works. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You put an equals sign in your trips array's second object's 'created' attribute.

```
vm.trips = [{
    name: "US Trip",
    created: new Date()
}, {
    name: "World Trip",
    created = new Date()
}];
```

should be

```
vm.trips = [{
    name: "US Trip",
    created: new Date()
}, {
    name: "World Trip",
    created: new Date()
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for seeing that!! Now I'm getting en error in console. See edit